# Why are my vertices pinching like this?

Tags: mesh, vertices

[image]

I'm practicing creating a character head from scratch, and when I apply a subD modifier to see how it looks, the vertices pinch like this. Anyone know why? The topology looks clean as far as I can tell when I go into edit mode.

Comment: check the faces normal, check the overlamp egde,vertices...or give us the blender file.

Comment: Consider. Backup you file.  Delete the problem areas which are few.  Redo the areas.

Comment: Alright, yup. Deleted the areas and redid it, thanks @atomicbezierslinger